# Can I prepare instant noodles in the microwave?

Tags: microwave, noodles

I want to prepare instant noodles in microwave. The instructions on the pack clearly mention a gas stove to be used, but I don't have access to one.

The instant noodles I am talking about are Nestle's maggy 2 minutes (that's how they brand it in India). Have a look at the the following Google image search link if it still doesn't ring a bell.

http://goo.gl/tBwF0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Maggi noodles you link to are just average ramen noodles, so can be cooked in the microwave quite easily.

1. Boil a kettle of water
2. Place the noodles in a microwavable bowl. You may need to break the noodles into pieces, but if you're careful with the boiling water you can sometimes soften the noodles in the middle enough to fold the block to make it all fit without breaking
3. Pour the flavour sachet (and any other curry powder/herbs) onto the dry noodles
4. Pour the boiling water onto the noodles, enough to cover the noodles, and if desired, a bit more for a bit of a soup
5. Put into the microwave, you can cover with a loose lid if desired, and microwave for around 2 minutes
6. Stir the noodles, separating any stuck-together blocks of noodles
7. Put back into the microwave for another 2-3 minutes (depending on your microwave's power)

I usually cook these kind in the microwave, since if I'm eating them I'm not usually in the mood for a proper cooking session. They do (depending on the kind of noodle) sometimes turn out slightly different when done in the microwave, as compared to boiling on hob, but both are nice as a snack.

Comment: Hmmm I've never had to boil water AND microwave before. And the amount of time you said to microwave after already adding boiling water seems excessive. I usually just let the noodles steep in boiling water for about 5 minutes covered and it's done. Or I just put faucet water into a bowl with the noodles and microwave for just 3 or so minutes.

Comment: Yes, I may have got the timings wrong for the thinner variety of ramen. I usually cook the thicker variety (Batchelor's Super Noodles), and even on the packet they have similar instructions to the ones I listed.

Comment: This is a good technique if you are adding other solid ingredients. As it makes it a one step cook. I wouldn't bother with step 6, just microwave 3 to 4 minutes

Answer (score 7):

You absolutely can — and in two different ways, depending on your preference.

The first is to place the noodles and cold water into a microwaveable bowl, and microwave on high for about 2-3 minutes, total. It can help to stir or "flip" the noodles halfway through. If the noodles aren't done to your satisfaction, continue microwaving them in 30-60 second intervals. Once heated through, add your flavor packet, stir and eat.

The other is to simply use the microwave to boil your water. Put your water in a microwave-safe vessel and microwave for a few minutes. It is a good idea to let it sit for a minute before moving it out of the microwave (microwave-boiled water can superheat without looking like it's boiling... be safe). Pour your boiled water over the noodles and flavor packet and cover. I often cover the bowl with a plate of the appropriate size. Let it sit for 3-5 minutes. Stir and eat.

Answer (score 2):

It is important not to insert the seasoning flavor early; as some of it gets away with the steam. Always put it at last and its better to cover it after, till you decide to eat.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You put the noodles in a bowl then put cold water in the bowl. Then you microwave it for about 2 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can! tried it just a few mins ago..though i din make instant noodles..but i made instant pasta! they are kinda same to cook..
just poot it in a microvavable pan..covered with a microvavable lid with just a little openning...and micro them for about 4 mins 30 secs or 5 mins..
Tadda..your instant pasta/noodles are ready!

Answer (score -1):

Use a flat ceramic plate. 
Details here: http://jerrin.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-make-perfect-microwave-maggi.html

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

You have to put 2 cups of water (for 1 pack of noodles)in a microwave safe bowl add the seasonings and noodles....start the microwave on 2 minutes.. IT WORKS...